# Is the set $\bigsqcup_{p\in M} \{v\in T_pM: |v|_g< r_p\}$open in $TM$?(where $r_p$ the injectivity radius at $p$)

Tags: exponential-function, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. (1)If $D_p$ is the largest domain on which $\exp_p$ can be a diffeomorphism, then is the set $$D=\bigsqcup_{p\in M} D_p$$ open in $TM$?  (2)Likewise, if we denote $r_p$ the injectivity radius at $p\in M$, then is the set $$D_1=\bigsqcup_{p\in M} \{v\in T_pM: |v|_g< r_p\}$$ open in $TM$?

Comment: Is the function $p \to r_p$ continuous?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But, I think this is also a good question.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how $D_p$ is defined, because I'm not sure how to make precise the notion of "largest" among open subsets of $T_pM$ on which $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @mollyerin Thanks. $D_p$should be $seg^o(p)$ i.e. the segment domain at $p$ minus the cut locus(cf. Petersen, Riemmanian Geometry(GTM 171),pp.139-141). I think the Lemma 15 in this reference shows that it is the largest open set we desire.

Comment: @Henry This is at least a precise definition of $D_p$, so I will think some about your question (1). (I am still not happy with the word "largest" here; I'll remark there can certainly be open domains of $T_pM$ on which $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism that are not contained within $seg^o(p)$. Picture the circle for easy examples.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is complete, then $D_1$ is open, which follows essentially from the fact that [$p \mapsto r_p$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754968/the-continuity-of-injectivity-radius). For instance, consider the map $f : TM \to TM$ given by
$$
   f : v \mapsto \frac{v}{r_p},
$$
where $p$ is the footpoint of $v$; $f$ is continuous, and your $D_1$ is the inverse image under $f$ of the open set
$$
  \lbrace v \in TM : ||v|| < 1 \rbrace.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the good answer.